# When will a Socket receive return 0 bytes and when will it throw a SocktException?

Tags: .net, sockets

Am I correct in saying that a Socket.Receive will throw a SocketException containing a connection reset message when the other side closes the socket. It will return 0 bytes if the other side calls Socket.Shutdown(Shutdown.Send).

This is what my testing has confirmed but the documentation doesn't state that explicity. I might just be getting the 0 byte read for some other reason.

Comment: Hard to be sure without setting up a test rig, but IIRC generally a cleanly closed socket will return 0 regardless of whether it had the send channel shutdown first

Answer (score 0):

My testing shows that you are right. Here some from MSDN :
"If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes." 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx